# How to calculate the frequency of pattern combination occurrences?

Tags: r, pattern-matching, combinations, bioinformatics, combinatorics

I'm trying to implement a method to calculate the frequency of motif combinations that was previously described in this paper (https://www.nature.com/articles/ng.2870). I'm a biologist and very beginner in R so it's been very difficult to do what seems a rather simple task...

I have 2 tab separated dataframes as inputs; dataframe1 contains a list of all motif combinations, something like this:

```
MotifCombID Motif1  Motif2  Motif3
          1    Sp1     YY1     NFY
          2    Sp1     YY1    KLF5
          3    Sp1     YY1     ETS
```

Dataframe2 contains all the motif occurrences per string, something like this:

```
StringID    Sp1 YY1 NFY  KLF5 ETS
       1      2   3   4     1   3
       2      0   1   0     2   0   
       3      0   0   2     1   5   
       4      1   0   1     0   0
```

What I just really want to do is to calculate the combinations of motifs/patterns listed in the df 1 (e.g., Combination 1: Sp1, YY1, NFY) using the data in df2, for all combinations listed in df1.

So I need 
1) to search if motif names in df1 match to motif names in df2;

2) if so, retrieve all columns;

3) multiply values in each row and then sum all values;

4) Return the 'frequency' of that motif combination (the result of step 3).

E.g.:

for MotifCombID 1 (Sp1, YY1, NFY) = (2*3*4)+(0*1*0)+(0*0*2)+(1*0*1) = 24

for MotifCombID 2 (Sp1, YY1, KLF5) = (2*3*1) + (0*1*2) + (0*0*1)+(1*0*0) = 6

for MotifCombID 3 (Sp1, YY1, ETS) = (2*3*3) + (0*1*0) + (0*0*5)+(1*0*0) = 18

etc...

These dataframes are rather big (df1:57155 x 3, df2: 71 motifs x 99583 strings) so I wanted to do this in a computationally efficient way.

Thanks so much for any help or giving me directions on where to get started with!

Comment: it would be clearer to understand if you show the expected output for this dummy example...

Comment: sure! 

for combination 1 (Sp1, YY1, NFY) = (2*3*4)+(0*1*0)+(0*0*2)+(1*0*1) = 24

for combination 2 (Sp1, YY1, KLF5) = (2*3*1) + (0*1*2) + (0*0*1)+(1*0*0) = 6

for combination 3 (Sp1, YY1, ETS) = (2*3*3) + (0*1*0) + (0*0*5)+(1*0*0) = 18

etc...

Comment: If you're a beginner in R, it may still be time to switch to python + pandas. R is useful when you want to use readily implemented data analyses packages that happen to be interfaced with R, but if you want to program your own methods, python may prove less frustrating in the long run.

Comment: Thanks! You're the second person within the last 24h to tell me this, will definitely put an effort on that. What about data visualisation/plotting? Do you reckon python will do as fine and friendly as R?

Answer (score 3):

Since your data is arranged rowwise, I transposed it so as to deal with columnwise data:

```
(dat2=data.frame(t(dat[-1])))
        X1   X2  X3
Motif1 Sp1  Sp1 Sp1
Motif2 YY1  YY1 YY1
Motif3 NFY KLF5 ETS
(dat3=data.frame(t(dat1[-1])))
     X1 X2 X3 X4
Sp1   2  0  0  1
YY1   3  1  0  0
NFY   4  0  2  1
KLF5  1  2  1  0
ETS   3  0  5  0
```

Then I wrote a function that computes the combinations:

```
fun=function(x)sum(sapply(dat3[rownames(dat3)%in%x,],prod))
sapply(dat2,fun)
X1 X2 X3 
24  6 18
```

Comment: Thanks a looot Onyambu! This looks really good! 


But for X1 it's giving me 12, guess it's only multiplying two columns (I think, YY1 x NFY). 


Your code is so condensed that I couldn't debug on my own, I guess it's something in the %in%x ?

Comment: In this example? That is crazy don't you think so? Because I am getting `24` and not `12`. Let me try something else: